# WPF UI not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I am lost...
I checked everything I coud think of..

1. DataContext is set !
2. No BindingErrors in DebugOutputWindow
3. INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented correctly (since Button-Clicks work ... )
4. Collection is updated (Count > 0)

But the Items in my ComboBox are not displayed.

What else can be wrong here ?

Here's my code:

```
private void Refresh(bool isAuto)
{
        List<DatabaseEntry> entries = GetBrokenJobs(isAuto);

        Collection.Clear();
        foreach (string jobName in entries.Select(x => x.Description).ToList())
        {
            Collection.Add(jobName);
        }
}
```

I am binding to a ComboxBox:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

private ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
{
    get {return _collection; }
    set
    {
        _collection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();//<= Has [CallerMemberName] in constructor ...
    }
}
```

And I am setting the DataContext like always ..

```
this.DataContext = MainViewModel.Instance;
```

Since all my Buttons and CheckBoxes work this might not be the origin ..

**EDIT**

Here is some more Xaml

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="10"                          
                      Grid.Column="1" 
                      Width="230"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsJobSelectorEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedJobItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: pls use Snoop to check your DataContext and Bindings at runtime. and pls remove Mode=TowWay and UpdateSourceTrigger - It makes no sense for Binding to the ItemsSource

Comment: Weired thing is: I have CheckBoxes, they work, buttons with Commands on the same viewmodel do too. DataContext is set 100%...

Comment: clueless without xaml

Comment: Collection.Add is not going to fire the setter of Collection. After you finish iterating the for loop to add the items, make a call to on property changed for Collection and see if that makes them display.

Comment: @TravisSapp Collection is an ObservableCollection. Clear and Add are already firing the CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Could we have some more XAML please? The issue might reside in how you bind the Text in your ComboBox.

Comment: Just `ComboBox` is not populated? Double check whether other controls have data from `ViewModel`.

Comment: Why does your edit with more XAML have the binding as Collection.JobBezeichnung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Bind the combobox item source to an ObservableCollection.

This is not required
**ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"**

Please use like this
**ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxList}"**
where ComboBoxList is an observable collection defined inside your data context.

Answer (score 0):

I know it kind of goes against what an observablecollection should do but I have had a problem in the past where Adding to an existing ObservableCollection is completely ignored.

If you try replacing the whole observablecollection so something along the lines of, it may force it to be updated:

List entries = GetBrokenJobs(isAuto);

Collection = new ObservableCollection(entries.Select(x => x.Description).ToList());